# Обучение перцептрона

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети

Не подскажите из-за чего во время обучения нейро-сети алгоритмом обратного распространения ошибки значение весов синапсов устанавливается на NaN - not a number. Притом через раз. Уменьшил количество нейронов - стало реже. как функцию активации использую сигмоиду.

Еще не могли бы скинуть литературу, в которой описан принцип алгоритма обратного распространения ошибки, т.е. доказательство того, что он действительно работает. Просто как-то неудобно принимать его как данность. Лучше понимаешь принцип - легче работать.

Заранее спасибо.

Кстати, если это важно, то пишу на java.

Comment: Кстати щас заметил, что я пытаюсь заставить первое значение выходного вектора обучить на 10 при одинаковых входных параметрах, и при том,что все выходные значения колеблются от нуля до одного.
По идее он не должен все равно выводить NaN. И кстати чему равно NaN. Как оно получается?

Comment: NaN - это зарезервированное значение для бесконечности, получается обычным образом: деление на ноль, экспонента от очень большого числа и т.п.

Comment: NaN - not a number это не бесконечность
бесконечность - Infinity
NaN получается при попытке к примеру перемножить строку на число, короче при любой математической операции со строкой

Comment: я не работал со строками.

Comment: Гы... а как умножить строку на число? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: Это наверное во всяких скриптах можно творить бог знает что с числами и строками.. вот там, наверное, и можно умножать чего хотие :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался в чем была ошибка.

Я выбрал неправильный подход к обучению) Я 100000 раз обучал мой перцептрон одними и теми же данными. Поэтому веса синапсов начинали зашкаливать - Infinity. А при делении или умножении числа на Infinity получается NaN.